# tikzpicture curved arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows

I am trying to make I diagram with two boxes, one above the other, and two arrows: I would like the arrows to be curved (that would be kind of circular flow diagram) and in just one direction.  Although, the best I could do searching by myself was one single straight bidirectional vertical arrow. Could someone help me with that ?

**Edit**

> Also I would like to know about other types of arrows. I am looking
>   for a thiker solid one but I couldn't find any yet. Could someone
>   point me in the right direction please?

**Extra question**

> How to make the text next to the arrows lay in the horizontal?

The code I used is that one :

```
\begin{document} 
\usepackage{color, colortbl} 
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes,backgrounds,fit}  
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
        \scalebox{.8}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance= 9em and 4em,
        sloped]
        \tikzset{
        box/.style = {
            fill=blue!15,
            shape=rectangle, 
            rounded corners,
                draw=blue!40, 
                align=center,
                %minimum size={10pt},
                text = black,
                font=\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont},
        dummybox/.style = {
            shape=circle,  
                align=center, 
                minimum size={width("rrrrrrrrrrr")+2pt}},
        arrow/.style={
            color=black,
            draw=blue,
            -latex,
                font=\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont},
        }

        \node[box](B1){Node $A$};
        \node[box, below = of B1](S1){Node $B$};
        \draw[arrow](B1) to node[above]{Flow: $\alpha$ } (S1);

        \draw[arrow](S1) to node[above]{Flow: $-\beta$ } (B1);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Pleas, complete your code  to small complete document, which we can copy to our computer and test then.

Comment: And preamble? Used package should be loaded in it. ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:**
Alternatively:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
node distance = 9em and 4em,
sloped,
   box/.style = {%
    shape=rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    draw=blue!40,
    fill=blue!15,
    align=center,
    font=\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont},
 arrow/.style = {%
    draw=blue!30,
    line width=2mm,% <-- select desired width
    -{Triangle[length=3mm]},
    shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm,
    font=\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont},
    }
\node[box](B1){Node $A$};
\node[box, below = of B1](S1){Node $B$};
\draw[arrow](B1) to [bend left,looseness=1.2] node[above] {Flow: $\alpha$} (S1);
\draw[arrow](S1) to [bend left,looseness=1.2] node[above] {Flow: $-\beta$} (B1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Text at arrows is aligned with it due to option `slanted` in `\tikzset{...}`. If you remove it, the text will appear horizontally aligned:

[image]

in this case the text at arrows is well aligned also if it is typed as label with help of library `quotes`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
node distance = 9em and 4em,
%    sloped, % <-- removed for horizontal align of arrows labels
    box/.style = {%
    shape=rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    draw=blue!40,
    fill=blue!15,
    align=center,
    font=\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont},
 arrow/.style = {%
    draw=blue!30,
    line width=2mm,% <-- select desired width
    -{Triangle[length=3mm]},
    shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm,
    font=\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont},
    }
\node[box](B1){Node $A$};
\node[box, below = of B1](S1){Node $B$};
\draw[arrow](B1) to [bend left,looseness=1.2,"Flow: $\alpha$"] (S1);
\draw[arrow](S1) to [bend left,looseness=1.2,"Flow: $-\beta$"] (B1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to make the text horizontal ?

Comment: Simple. Just remove option `slanted` from `\tikzset`. See addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain curved arrow with `to[out=alpha,in=beta]`.  where `alpha`  is the angle at which the curve leaves the start coordinate, and `beta` is the angle at which the curve reaches the target coordinate.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color, colortbl} 
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes,backgrounds,fit}  
\begin{document} 
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
        \scalebox{.8}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance= 9em and 4em,
        sloped]
        \tikzset{
        box/.style = {
            fill=blue!15,
            shape=rectangle, 
            rounded corners,
                draw=blue!40, 
                align=center,
                %minimum size={10pt},
                text = black,
                font=\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont},
        dummybox/.style = {
            shape=circle,  
                align=center, 
                minimum size={width("rrrrrrrrrrr")+2pt}},
        arrow/.style={
            color=black,
            draw=blue,
            -latex,
                font=\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont},
        }

        \node[box](B1){Node $A$};
        \node[box, below = of B1](S1){Node $B$};
        \draw[arrow](B1.west) to [out=190,in=170] node[above]{Flow: $\alpha$ } (S1.west);

        \draw[arrow](S1.east) to [out=10,in=-10] node[above]{Flow: $-\beta$ } (B1.east);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]